# Java version shows as 1.5 after Java 6 installed on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: java, macos

1. I've installed Java 6 from this location:
   http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1359

Java SE 6 is at the top of the list in Java preferences.

Yet, when I type in java -version, it gives me :
java version "1.5.0_30"

1. I note that /Library/Java/Home is pointing to 
   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home

I also note that there is no corresponding
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home

Instead 
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/1.6 and 
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/1.6.0 are both links pointing to 
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents

Why the discrepancy?

1. I note that /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/CurrentJDK points to 
   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/1.5.0

and 
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/Current points to 
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/A

What the heck is "A" ?

Comment: I do not know how it works on MacOS, but you've checked the environment variables?

Comment: Did you check [Superuser:Java 1.6 on Mac OS X 10.5?](http://superuser.com/questions/100078/java-1-6-on-mac-os-x-10-5)

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` points to `\Library\Java\Home`, which is a link pointing to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home`

Comment: @ring bearer, I checked the link and tried Java Preferences with no luck. java -version still returns 1.5.  I even tried disabling 1.5 through Java preferences. java -version still returns 1.5, which leads me to wonder if this utility is doing anything at all.

Comment: Ok, I had to unset JAVA_HOME in order for the Java preferences to kick in (unset JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile).

Comment: This was very helpful: [Java 1.6 Finally Available for Mac OS X](http://blogs.oracle.com/cmar/entry/java_1_6_finally_available)

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the below steps to change the Java version to 1.5:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
3. Type sudo ln -fhsv 1.5 CurrentJDK

Refer [Changing-Java-Version-in-Mac](http://techmindviews.blogspot.com/2011/10/changing-java-version-mac-1046.html)